# How to get select value for one element?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a repeater field that has a yes/no select. If not, then a class is added to the div, if yes, then nothing happens. Now, when selecting one element with the value "no", the class is added to all elements. How can I add it for one element?

```js
$team_cards = get_field('team_cards');

$noimage = '';

foreach ($team_cards as $item) {
    if ($item["yes_no"] == "no") {
        $noimage = "no-image";
    }
}

 <div class="<?php echo $noimage ?>"></div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `<div>` be inside of the loop? Currently what you have is a foreach loop that if even one of the $item has a property of 'yes_no' with the value of no, you assign $noimage a string, so it will always be with that new string now

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<?php 
$team_cards = get_field('team_cards');

$noimage = '';

foreach ($team_cards as $item) {
    if ($item["yes_no"] == "no") {
?>
        <div class="no-image"></div>
    <?php 
}else{ ?>
        <div class="”></div>
<?php
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$team_cards = get_field('team_cards');

foreach ($team_cards as $item) {
    if ($item["yes_no"] == "no") {
        $noimage = "no-image";
    }else{
        $noimage = "";
    }
}

 <div class="<?php echo $noimage ?>"></div>
```